# Searching column with string for wildcard match

Tags: regex, excel

I can't seem to figure out the VLOOKUP magic needed to make this work as I want it to.

See, what I've got is a column B containing filenames, like this:

```
[COLUMN B]
./11001 Boogie Oogie Oogie (A Taste Of Honey).wav
./11001 Rescue Me (A Taste Of Honey).wav 
./11001 Sukiyaki (A Taste Of Honey).wav
./11002 Memory (Acker Bilk).wav
./11002 Stuck On You (Acker Bilk).wav
./11002 Could I Have This Dance (Acker Bilk).wav
./11002 Do That To Me One More Time (Acker Bilk).wav
./11002 This Masquerade (Acker Bilk).wav
./11002 Just Once (Acker Bilk).wav
```

And so on for 6220 entries.

I have another column, Column E, which contains a TRACK NAME which is present within the filename. Looks like this:

```
American Patrol
Artistry In Rhythm
Begin The Beguine
Big John's Special
Cherokee
```

For example. So what I want to do is, in another column I want to search through Column B using the strings from Column E and then returning the matched string from Column B.

So if we imagine I put this formula in the C Column starting in the same row as the American Patrol track name, it would search through the range in Column B and return this:

```
./11249 American Patrol (BBC Big Band).wav
./11249 Artistry In Rhythm (BBC Big Band).wav
./11249 Begin The Beguine (BBC Big Band).wav
```

And so on.

I tried doing this formula

```
=VLOOKUP(E2;B2:B6235;2;TRUE)
```

So, this returns a file name, but it seems to have matched all the filenames and are just returning whichever result I specify in the col_index variable, so now it returns the second match (basically, just the second row in Column B) and if I put a 3 instead, it would just return the third hit, again having matched all the file names, it seems..

I'm not that familiar with Excel functions, so I'm not sure where to look for the solution beyond this.

Comment: By using 'true' you are asking for the closest match. And there is no match as you are trying to match `Amercian Patrol` to strings that all start with `./11001` etc. That's why it just returns the last entry in the column

Comment: The output example is based on the example of my column E. I thought the context would be clear from the three examples and must have been clear enough since @Jeeped answered it perfectly below.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `TRUE` as a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)'s *range_lookup* parameter on unsorted data. You can, however, wrap your track title in wildcards to achieve the search you are looking for.

[image: Song Title lookup]

The formula in C1 is,

```
=INDEX(B:B, MATCH("*"&E1&"*",B:B, 0))
```

... or,

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&E1&"*",B:B, 1, FALSE)
```

They accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Perfect, this does exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!